# Coldfusion 11 | Internet Explorer 11 (Only) Cookies not correctly working in HTTPS mode

Tags: internet-explorer, session, cookies, coldfusion

I have a very strange issue that I need help with. I have a site which uses Coldfusion 11 on windows 2008 R2 IIS 7. When some users login with Internet Explorer, they are redirected to the main login page. It will not allow those users to login properly. Users using Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox have no issues logging into the system. We have checked the code that sets both session and cookie variables and can't find any reason why the login does not work on Internet Explorer. We have used Ben Nadel's code (http://www.bennadel.com/blog/730-testing-coldfusion-session-cookie-acceptance.htm) to verify the creation of cookies and have found that in secure mode (https) cookies are not being set.

Upon the users’ login, we reset the session and cookies scopes. We also validated that the cfid and cftokens are the same between cookie and session scopes. In addition, we’ve  used structdelete to kill the cfid and cftoken and still find that it is not properly working. If you whitelist the web site  in Internet Explorer, it fixes the issue. However, we do not want to ask our clients to do this. httpOnly cookies are enabled in ColdFusion 11 Administrator under Memory Variables. We think that either the wild card digital certificate, a setting in Coldfusion 11, or something in the code is the root cause. It works on all other browsers i.e. Firefox, Chrome, Safari,  and Opera.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you setting httponly="true" and secure="true" in your cfcookie call?

Comment: At the moment we are not. Those however are both set in Coldfusion Admin. Is there an upside or difference to setting them inline in the cfcookie code?